# In SQL how to find data rows separated within few seconds of each other

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in which sensor events are recorded. And a random log is selected for testing every hour at a random time. I want to find N events which are within T seconds of each hourly picking.

Data looks like this

```
eventID eventTs             picked_for_testing
123     2021-04-01 13:21:45         0
3532    2020-12-16 08:31:12         1
987341  2021-04-01 13:21:41         1
```

Event 1 and 3 both happened within 4 seconds of each other. I want to find all such events that happened within say 10 seconds.

I was able to get it by doing a cross join of all the selected events with non-selected and then did a time diff between the eventTs and then filtered it. But it is taking too long because of the number of events in the data.

Is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that requirements [BigQuery analytic functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts) seems to be the way to go. In particular [navigation functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions).

It is quite hard to give you a proper query without knowing the exact outcome you are looking for. I'll assume you only want a table with the following schema:

eventID, next_eventID_within_10

So, this query will do the job:

```
WITH data as (
SELECT 123 as eventID, timestamp("2021-04-01 13:21:45") as eventTs, 0 as picked_for_testing
UNION ALL
SELECT 3532 as eventID, timestamp("2020-12-16 08:31:12") as eventTs, 1 as picked_for_testing
UNION ALL 
SELECT 987341 as eventID, timestamp("2021-04-01 13:21:41") as eventTs, 1 as picked_for_testing
UNION ALL 
SELECT 87345874 as eventID, timestamp("2021-04-01 13:21:49") as eventTs, 1 as picked_for_testing)

, tmp as (
SELECT 
  eventID, 
  picked_for_testing,
  eventTs,
  IF(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(LEAD(eventTs) OVER (ORDER BY eventTs), eventTs, SECOND) <= 10, LEAD(eventID) OVER (ORDER BY eventTs), Null) as next_eventID_within_10
FROM data)

SELECT eventID, next_eventID_within_10 
FROM tmp 
WHERE next_eventID_within_10 IS NOT NULL
```

[image]